# Installing ArcSDE 10 on SQL Server 2008 R2 Cluster 64bit or 32bit?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, installation

I am looking for Tips an Tricks on installing ArcSDE on SQL Server 2008 R2 Cluster. Our IT division would like to have all the databases on their new 2008 cluster.

I've only done standard install before and I don't know how to go about it.

Does SDE have to be install on each of the cluster servers?

Does it have to be installed outside the cluster , on a seperate machine?

Comment: It's similar to the 2005 "ArcSDE clustered installation the software should be installed on the system disk of each node." http://www.esri.com/systemsint/kbase/docs/arcsde-sqlserver.pdf

Comment: SQL 2012 (Enterprise Version) has Geo-Clustering and it much faster than 2008 R2 - http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/future-editions/sql2012-editions.aspx

Comment: @Mapperz Is it relevant to the question? I believe that SQL Server 2017 (Universe Version) will be faster than SQL 2012 (Enterprise Version).

Comment: @Mapperz after call to ESRI Technical Support. The document esri.com/systemsint/kbase/docs/arcsde-sqlserver.pdf is the most recent that they have.

Comment: i got a trouble with MS Cluster. When i try connect direct to node1 the connection is succefuln but when i try connect with cluster Host i get "Failed to connect to the specified server. Bad Login user". Thanks!

Comment: This would be a good question instead of an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you have an existing R2 cluster...

Create a domain service account and give it "Log on as a service" on each node.
Open port 5151 in the Firewall of each node for the SDE service.
Install ArcSDE on both nodes. ( Do not Run post- install on second node!)
Run the Post Install wizard and select complete.
Use the cluster sql name\instance to create the DB and repository.
Complete the authorization wizard using the sql cluster name.
When creating the service enter the domain account info from earlier . You will also use the DB name created in the earlier wizard. Use the SQL clustername\Instance for "SQL Server Instance name"  and SQl Cluster name for "Server name".
After post install is complete make sure the service starts, and that your domain account is starting it. Then stop the service and change startup to "Manual".

Run post-install on second node and install the service only using settings in previous step. (Do not start the service when prompted) Change service to "Manual"

Open Failover cluster manager and right-click the SQL Server () and "Add Resource"  followed by "Generic Service"

Select the ArcSDE service and finish the wizard.

Right click the newly created resource and select properties .

Delete contents of  the startup parameters box
Add SQL Server Agent as dependency.

*Optional if using SQL for other purposes besides ArcSDE*
Uncheck  both boxes under "Policies tab" so the SDE service will not cause a failover.

Right click the SDE service resource and bring online. If it is successful test failover.